# tastypie- The model '' has an empty attribute

Tags: python, django, tastypie

When using fields.ToManyField() to do a reverse relationship I'm getting the following error when hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/environment_test_device/?format=json
```

I'm seeing

```
The model '' has an empty attribute 'device_type_set' and doesn't allow a null value.
```

I'm wondering why the model is ''. I'm guessing that my path to api isn't being set properly. Is there a way to verify the path to the file is correct or why i'm getting this error? I really didn't understand either what 'device_type_set' should be called. I was looking at http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name but "author_set" really didn't correspond to anything in the example given

My model is

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'device_type'

class Environment(models.Model):
    environment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    environment_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'environment'

class Test(models.Model):
    test_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'test'

class EnvironmentTestDevice(models.Model):
    environment_test_device_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    device_type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'environment_test_device'
```

and my api.py is

```
class DeviceTypeResource(ModelResource):
    environment_test_device = fields.ToManyField('resources.EnvironmentTestDeviceResource', 'device_type_set', related_name = 'device_type', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = DeviceType.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'device_type'

class EnvironmentResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Environment.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'environment'

class TestResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'test'

class EnvironmentTestDeviceResource(ModelResource):
    device_type = fields.ForeignKey(DeviceTypeResource, 'device_type', full=True, null=True)
    test = fields.ForeignKey(TestResource, 'test', full=True, null=True)
    environment = fields.ForeignKey(EnvironmentResource, 'environment', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = PipelineTestDevice.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'environment_test_device'
```

On a side note for the following line

```
 environment_test_device = fields.ToManyField('resources.EnvironmentTestDeviceResource', 'device_type_set', related_name = 'device_type', full=True)
```

I have commented it out I'm able to get back a proper json response but I'm assuming I will need the reverse relations. Also I have tried setting 'resources.EnvironmentTestDeviceResource' to 
'project.api.resources.EnvironmentTestDeviceResource' and 'project.api.EnvironmentTestDeviceResource' and received the same error response. 'project' is the name of my app

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is name of attribute. Use `devicetype_set` instead of `device_type_set`. But you should test it up in Django shell. Here [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name) <- there is a note saying that Django creates `reversed_name` name based on lowercase class name:

`DeviceType` becomes `devicetype` + `_set`

### Edit for your comment

Documentation says it should be path to the resource. If it is in the same file I would use this form:

```
environment_test_device = fields.ToManyField('EnvironmentTestDeviceResource', 'devicetype_set', related_name = 'device_type', full=True)
```

If this doesn't work you should try to go with absolute path I will need to see your `INSTALLED_APPS` and project folder structure.

[Documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name)

Comment: what should the path.to.api be ?